# Major/Minor diagonals and row are not registering as a win in connect four project

Tags: java

I've been working on this connect four project for almost a week now and I think I have completed it, but I cannot get the major diagonal, minor diagonal or the row to register as a win if 4 chips are placed in the correct patterns.

If I could please have someone look over my code and let me know what I have done wrong I would really appreciate it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class connect4
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    char[][] connectFourGrid= new char[6][7];
    displayGrid(connectFourGrid);
    playConnectFour(connectFourGrid);
}




      //Plays the game 




public static void playConnectFour(char[][] connectFourGrid)
{   
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean gameOver = false, playersTurn = true;
    int columnPosition = 0;
    char chipColor;
    while(!gameOver)
    {
        if(playersTurn)
        {
            System.out.print("Drop a an 'x' in column (0,6):");
            chipColor = 'X';
        }
        else
        {   
            System.out.print("Drop a an 'o' in column (0,6):");
            chipColor = 'O';
        }
        columnPosition = input.nextInt();
        while(columnPosition < 0 || columnPosition > 6)
        {
            System.out.print("Column Position must be between 0 to 6, try again");
            columnPosition = input.nextInt();
        }
        playersTurn = !playersTurn;

        if (dropChip(connectFourGrid, columnPosition, chipColor))        
            playersTurn = !playersTurn;
        else
        {
            displayGrid(connectFourGrid);

            if(gameStatus(connectFourGrid, columnPosition, chipColor))
            {
                gameOver = true;
                System.out.print(chipColor + " won! game over.");
            }
            else if(checkTie(connectFourGrid))
            {
                gameOver = true;
                System.out.print("It's a tie!");
            }
        }

    }

    input.close();
}



/**
 * This is where the check for a tie takes place
 */


public static boolean checkTie(char[][] connectFourGrid)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < connectFourGrid[0].length; i++)
        if(connectFourGrid[0][i] == 0)
            return false;

    return true;

/**
 * This is where the gameStatus will update if 4 x's or o's are found horizontally, vertically or diagonally    
 */


}
public static boolean gameStatus(char[][] connectFourGrid, int columnPosition, char chipColor)
{
    int rowPosition = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < connectFourGrid.length; i++)
        if (connectFourGrid[i][columnPosition] != 0)
    {
        rowPosition = 1;
        break;

    }
    if(checkColumn(connectFourGrid, columnPosition, chipColor,rowPosition))
        return true;
    if(checkRow(connectFourGrid, columnPosition, chipColor,rowPosition))
        return true;
    if(checkMajorDiagonal(connectFourGrid, columnPosition, chipColor,rowPosition))
        return true;
    if(checkMinorDiagonal(connectFourGrid, columnPosition, chipColor,rowPosition))
        return true;

    return false;
}




/*
 * checks for four chips in minor diagonal
 */



public static boolean checkMinorDiagonal(char[][] connectFourGrid, int columnPosition, char chipColor, int rowPosition)
{
    int chipCounter = 1;

    for(int i = rowPosition + 1, j = columnPosition - 1; i < connectFourGrid.length && j>= 0; i++, j--)
        if(chipColor == connectFourGrid[i][j])
            chipCounter++;
        else
            break;

    if (chipCounter >= 4)
        return true;

    for(int i = rowPosition - 1, j = columnPosition + 1; i >= 0 && j < connectFourGrid[0].length; i--, j++)
        if (chipColor == connectFourGrid[i][j])
            chipCounter++;
        else
            break;

    if (chipCounter >= 4)
        return true;

    return false;
}

/*
 * checks for four chips in major diagonal
 */

public static boolean checkMajorDiagonal(char[][] connectFourGrid, int columnPosition, char chipColor, int rowPosition)
{
    int chipCounter = 1;

    for(int i = rowPosition - 1, j = columnPosition - 1; i < 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--)
        if (chipColor == connectFourGrid[i][j])
            chipCounter++;
        else
            break;

    if (chipCounter >= 4)
        return true;

    for(int i = rowPosition + 1, j = columnPosition + 1; i < connectFourGrid.length && j < connectFourGrid[0].length; i++, j++)
        if (chipColor == connectFourGrid[i][j])
            chipCounter++;
        else
            break;

    if (chipCounter >= 4)
        return true;

    return false;
}



/*
 * checks for four chips in a row
 */





public static boolean checkRow(char[][] connectFourGrid, int columnPosition, char chipColor, int rowPosition)
{
    int chipCounter = 1;

    for (int i = columnPosition - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (chipColor == connectFourGrid[rowPosition][i])
            chipCounter++;
        else
            break;

    if (chipCounter >= 4)
        return true;

    for(int i = columnPosition + 1; i < connectFourGrid[0].length; i++)
        if (chipColor == connectFourGrid[rowPosition][i])
            chipCounter++;
        else
            break;

    if (chipCounter >= 4)
        return true;


    return false;
}


/*
 * checks for four chips in a column
 */




public static boolean checkColumn(char[][] connectFourGrid, int columnPosition, char chipColor, int rowPosition)
{
    int chipCounter = 1;

    if ((rowPosition + 4) <=6)
        for (int i = rowPosition + 1; i <= (rowPosition + 3); i++)
            if(chipColor == connectFourGrid[i][columnPosition])
                chipCounter++;
            else 
                break;
    if(chipCounter == 4)
        return true;

    return false;
}




/**
 * Drops a chip to bottom of column picked, if the column is full asks to place again
 */ 

public static boolean dropChip(char[][] connectFourGrid, int columnPosition, char chipColor)
{
    for (int i = connectFourGrid.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (connectFourGrid[i][columnPosition] == 0)
        {  
            connectFourGrid[i][columnPosition] = chipColor;
            return false;
        }
    System.out.println("Column is full, " + chipColor + " player, try again");
    return true;
}



//Displays the grid





public static void displayGrid(char[][] connectFourGrid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < connectFourGrid.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < connectFourGrid[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print("|" + connectFourGrid[i][j]);
        System.out.println("|");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < connectFourGrid.length; i++);
        System.out.print("---");
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part in the `gameStatus` method is causing your issue:

```
int rowPosition = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < connectFourGrid.length; i++)
    if (connectFourGrid[i][columnPosition] != 0)
{
    rowPosition = 1;
    break;

}
```

The row position will only ever be equal to 1, but for your code to work shouldn't the rowPosition be able to go from 0 to 6.

Also, have a think about how this is working and how `checkMajorDiagonal` and `checkMinorDiagonal` work, because your code fails to check any combination that starts in row 0.

You need to add your own debug code and find the answer yourself.

Example showing two lines of debugging code added to the `checkMajorDiagonal` method:

```
public static boolean checkMajorDiagonal(char[][] connectFourGrid, int columnPosition, char chipColor, int rowPosition)
{
    int chipCounter = 1;
    //Debug code on the line below to print out helpful information
    System.out.println("Chip position: "+columnPosition+","+rowPosition);
    for (int i = rowPosition - 1, j = columnPosition - 1; i < 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--)
    {
        //Debug code on the line below to print out helpful information
        System.out.println("Checking chip: "+i+","+j);
        if (chipColor == connectFourGrid[i][j])
        {
```

Comment: I have fixed the problem. Thank you for pointing out where I had messed up, all I needed to do was set rowPosition equal to "i" and not 1.